# Eclipse: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi guys this is my problem:

```
[2016-03-17 15:00:17 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2016-03-17 15:00:17 - HuSe] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

Please, help me because i don't find solution.

I have 3 projects of which one is the main project (HuSe) and 2 instead are libraries (MoST and appcompact_v7).
When I try to run the project, Eclipse shows me this message. Other threads I read I understand that the problem is because in the MoST library there is

```
"support-v4-13.0.0.jar" in MoST library
```

that conflicts with

```
"android-support-v4.jar" in appcompact_v7 library
```

Indeed, they contains the same class names.
If you can help this is what there is inside the bin/dexedLibs:

[Fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2XQj.png)

Please help me because this problem make me crazy.

Sorry for my english.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in that you have two libraries with the same package (android-support-v4), but they have different versions. So you need copy/past library from one project to second. Hope it will fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. I must copy/paste "support-v413.0.0.jar" in app compact_v7 ?? or i add to one library the other library?

Comment: You must copy/paste "support-v413.0.0.jar" in app compact_v7 or otherwise. But the point is you need the same version of android-support-v4 in both dependencies.

Comment: I try to copy support-v413.0.0.jar in MoST/libs but when i run i have the same problem :(

Comment: You also need to remove old support-v4 library from MoST/libs

Comment: Great! If it works now, accept and upwote the answer, please!)